# Pyqt5, как добавить checkbox в QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory?

Tags: pyqt5, checkbox

Мне нужно открыть диалог выбора папки c помощью QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory, и в него добавить checkbox.
Штатно это сделать, судя по всему, нет возможности. На просторах интернета прочитал, что лучше поместить в отдельное окно виджеты QFileDialog и checkbox, но как это правильно сделать информации не нашёл.
В настоящее время открываю диалог без чекбокса, примерно так:
folder = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory (self, 'Select folder', path, QtWidgets.QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly)

Comment: Что за checkbox?

Comment: QCheckBox, флажок

Comment: Понятно, что флажок. Зачем он нужен?

Comment: Ну в моём случае для того, чтобы в случае его установки в True программа добавляла в список не просто выбранную папку, а сканировала её содержимое и добавляла все найденные подпапки и файлы (не глубже корня выбранной папки). Не хочется делать лишнее окно для этого.

Comment: А как вы у вас организован вызов диалога выбора папки? При запуске программы сразу, или в каком-то окне кнопка нажимается с тремя точками? Можно же заранее где-нибудь эту галочку поставить, то есть еще до вызова диалога выбора директории )

Comment: У меня в главном окне программы рядом со списком источников (файлов и папок) есть кнопка "Add folder", при нажатии на которую вызывается диалог.

Comment: Ну и добавьте туда галочку типа "Сканировать в глубину?"

Comment: Я такой вариант рассматривал, но мне кажется, что это будет не очень красиво выглядеть, окно и так уже довольно сильно загружено элементами. К тому же там кроме этой есть ещё три кнопки рядом, и будет довольно сложно визуально выделить, к чему эта галочка относится.

Comment: Я вам рекомендую еще раз посмотреть в этом направлении. Исходите из того, что стандартный диалог вы изменить не сможете, а если писать свой, то это будет дороже, на мой взгляд, нежели подправить исходный интерфейс

Comment: Ну если так и не найду, как правильно сделать, придётся либо так, либо отдельным мини окном делать. Насчёт дороговизны - это не проблема, я программу для себя пишу, а как готова будет - выложу под GPL. Может, пригодится кому.